# How to sign a text file using X509 certificate in Java?

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, digital-signature, x509certificate

I have exported a class 3 Digital certificate and I am able to get the details from the object named cert as seen below. I intend to sign a text file using this certificate. However since I exported this certificate without the private key, I am unable to proceed. I have shared a snippet below the image which has tags.

This is the file saved as .txt and the tags  and  will be the result of the signing process. So basically the raw payload will only have the other tags before the signing process.

My Questions:

1. Am I on the right track to digitally sign the text file from backend?
2. Should the access of the certificate be handled on the client side using Javascript

   ```
    try (InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream("D:\\New folder\\TestCertificate.cer")) {
         CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
         X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)cf.generateCertificate(inStream);

         cert.checkValidity();
         System.out.println("This is public key :  " + cert.getPublicKey());
         System.out.println("This is certificate type: " + cert.getType());

         // Code to access a txt file and sign it with the certificate.

     } catch (CertificateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
   ```

[image]

```
<MessageInfo>
<SenderIden>XSB000000000</SenderIden>
<SenderSP>100023193</SenderSP>
<Data><![CDATA[{IFN515}{XSB000000000}{XYZ12345} 
  {
  :16R:GENL
  :20C::SEME//A23P8W4
  :23G:NEWM
  :98A::PREP//20220221
  :22F::TRTR//TRAD
   ]]></Data>
  <SubscriberDS>MIIJuwYJKoZIhvcNAQcCoI</SubscriberDS>
  <ServiceProviderDS>MIIJuwYJKoZI</ServiceProviderDS>
  </MessageInfo>
```

Comment: First, signing operation requires private key. Only public certificate is not sufficient. Second, text files do not have standardized signed version, so it is unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi @Crypt32 thanks for responding. I have edited the question with the payload that is to be signed. It is refered as File.txt but has xml tags for the information. Presently I am able to sign this payload and the signature is seen in the tags   SubscriberDS and ServiceProviderDS since this is an applet based application. This does not work on modern browsers. I am trying to modify the code so that I can make it work on chrome.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly that you want to use the certificate on client, not on server?

Comment: @Crypt32 Yes, we want to use the certificate on the client.

Comment: You need to use some client side PKI library (pkijs, for example, or other WebCrypto library) and get permissions from browser, I.e. user must explicitly allow your website to access client certs and keys.

Comment: @Crypt32 will PKI and WebCrypto work for chrome, firefox etc? I will start my POCs in this direction then. Any links which you can suggest for PKIjs/WebCrypto as a starting point to understand? And I presume if not through applets there is no other option to access the certs and keys from backend Java code. Is it?

Comment: Here is your start point: https://pkijs.org

Comment: @Crypt32 Based on your inputs I set out on a proof of concept and started evaluating webextensions. There is a chrome.certificateProvider API. Can you please comment if it could lead me to the expected path?