# Can browser certificate be used for signing payload using web extension on Firefox

Tags: java, firefox, encryption, certificate, firefox-addon-webextensions

I have been pursuing an implementation where an xml payload can be digitally signed using the digital certificate. I have elaborated my question previously [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71319526/how-to-sign-a-text-file-using-x509-certificate-in-java)

I decided to try using webextensions to perform this target of mine. I started off my POC with

```
   {
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Test extension",
"version": "1.0",
"description": "Test extension.",
"icons": {
    "48": "icons/border-48.png"
},
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
},
"permissions": [
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "<all_urls>"
]
}
```

And the following background.js from a lead I got online

```
                var log = console.log.bind(console)

            log(`\n\nTLS browser extension loaded`)

            // https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns
            var ALL_SITES = { urls: ['<all_urls>'] }

            // Mozilla doesn't use tlsInfo in extraInfoSpec 
            var extraInfoSpec = ['blocking']; 

            // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onHeadersReceived
            browser.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(async function(details){
                log(`\n\nGot a request for ${details.url} with ID ${details.requestId}`)

                // Yeah this is a String, even though the content is a Number
                var requestId = details.requestId

                var securityInfo = await browser.webRequest.getSecurityInfo(requestId, {
                    certificateChain: true,
                    rawDER: false
                });

                log(`securityInfo: ${JSON.stringify(securityInfo, null, 2)}`)

            }, ALL_SITES, extraInfoSpec) 

            log('Added listener')
```

I am getting the below output on Firefox console after adding this as a custom extension. However it is just informing the certificate details of the sites I am visiting. With this foundation I needed help with a starting point where I can use the certificate on my own browser and sign a document as I am pursuing. Any inputs will be of great help. Thanks!

[image: This is the output I am getting on Firefox console]

Comment: The first comment of your other question tells you that you cannot sign something using a public key, you need the private key. And it has to be your private key, not some random website's key.

Comment: Thanks @PresidentJamesK.Polk for the response. I understood the requirement of the private key from the previous question. I am trying to use the class 3 certificate which I purchased (listed in my browser certificate list) to sign an xml payload. Two options for this I got to after lots of searching i. Use Webcrypto API or ii. Create Webextension. This question of mine has code of a webextension i created. Can I perform my signing requirement using chrome.certificateProvider etc ?