# How to get browser certificate to digitally sign a payload using Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, certificate

I am working on a chrome extension to get access to the list of certificates on my browser (Including the class 3 certificate I purchased).

This is the manifest.json

```
 {
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Coding Train Extension 2",
"version": "0.001",
"permissions": ["storage", "activeTab", "scripting"],
"content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches":["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["content.js"]
    }
],
 "background":{
   "scripts": ["background.js"]
 },
 "browser_action":{
   "default_icon": "logo.png"

 }
}
```

This is the background.js

```
 console.log("This is inside background...");
 chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(collectAvailableCertificates);

 function collectAvailableCertificates() {
   // Return all certificates that this Extension can currently provide.
   // For example:
   return [{
     certificateChain: [new Uint8Array()],
     supportedAlgorithms: ['RSASSA_PKCS1_v1_5_SHA256']
    }];
   }
```

In this test, the content.js is not being used much. I have an icon of the extension on browser and on its click I am triggering the background.js.
I am trying to emulate the APIs provided in the Chrome API documentation https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/certificateProvider/

How to call the methods like collectAvailableCertificates(), handleSignatureRequest(request) as seen in the document is what I am pursuing. My aim is to use this purchased certificate to digitally sign an xml payload.

Answer (score 1):

The `certificateProvider` API has an entirely different goal in mind.

It's **only available for Chrome OS**  as a way to manage certificate authentication **for web requests** - and not any other use of certificates (you seem to be aiming to sign an arbitrary payload in your code).

It also does not provide any cryptography required to use a certificate for signing, that's outside its scope (in fact, the extension using it is expected to implement signatures themselves), nor will it give you access to the OS certificate store if your certificate is stored there.

All this API does it **make the browser aware what certificates made are available (by the extension) when a web server requests HTTPS client certificate authentication.**

Nothing less, nothing more. Some Chrome APIs exist only for management functions on Chrome OS where other interfaces are unavailable.

The information regarding Chrome OS restriction was available on the documentation website [as late as Oct 2021](https://web.archive.org/web/20211015050419/https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/certificateProvider/), but does not seem to be reflected in the current one, [which is a documentation website bug](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/developer.chrome.com/issues/2298). And it's not like it's been extended to work elsewhere - that would be mentioned on [the What's New page](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/whatsnew/), but it again confirms in Oct 2021 that it's a "Chrome OS API" and has no mentions since.

You should be looking at Web crypto APIs instead, e.g. [`SubtleCrypto.sign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/sign), but that would mean including your private key in the extension itself.

---

**EDIT:** Actually, Chrome has another related API, [`chrome.platformKeys`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/platformKeys/), that may allow access to the OS certificate store (if that is your situation - needing to use an installed certificate without including it into the extension).

It can be used to request the public/private key out of the OS store and further use its own version of `SubtleCrypto` to work with them.

Comment: Thanks @Xan for the detailed insights! I am supposed to do the signing using the purchased Class 3 certificate and its private key cannot be extracted. Can you please confirm that I can use SubtleCrypto.sign with this certificate of which I cannot access the private key?

Comment: What is your situation? The certificate is imported in the OS certificate store?

Comment: Hi @Xan  :
1. The existing application is Java applet based. 
2. As a result the application as of now is able to work on IE where the requirement to select a certificate from the list of certificates installed on browser. We are able to select the certificate list using a dropdown box.
3. Next step is to sign the payload using this certificate.
4. We are trying to get rid of applet and get this running on chrome. 
5. My earlier question gives more insights.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71319526/how-to-sign-a-text-file-using-x509-certificate-in-java

Comment: As someone mentioned in that question, digital signature happens with the message + private key. A certificate on its own doesn't contain the private key required to do that. *If* you have the private key (as a file, or imported in the OS certificate store), you can use SubtleCrypto (and possibly `chrome.platformKeys` in case of OS store) to sign a message. If you don't have the private key, what you ask is impossible.